# How to fit multiple curves to a single scatter plot of data?

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning, curve-fitting

I have data from distinct curves, and want to fit each of them individually. However, the data is mixed into a single array, so first I believe I need a way to separate the data.

[image: This is an example of what the data looks like]

I know that each of the individual curves is under the family A/x+B. As of now I cut out each of the curves by hand and curve fit, but would like to automate this process, have the computer separate these curves a fit them. I attempted to use machine learning, but didn't know where to start, what packages to use. I am using python, but can also use C++, in fact I hope to transfer it to C++ by the end. Where do you think I should start, is it worth it to use unsupervised machine learning, or is there a better way to separate the data?

The expected curves:

[image: I hope to end with equations for these lines]

[An example of the data](https://github.com/ladouce7/Data_Points)

Comment: Can you share with us such an array?

Comment: I had a very similar problem myself, perhaps this is useful https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-trees

Comment: I ended up solcivoninving my problem as such: https://gitlab.com/nathan_vanthof/regression-tree-algorithm-with-linear-regression-models-in-each-leaf I think if you take the ln of y, plop that in, print the decision tree and take the exp of the resulting linear relations, it could work

Comment: Some of the time this equation can be more complex, so would this still be possible with a graph that cannot be linearized easily?

Comment: @Nathan please see my answer to this question, no log, exp or decision trees needed as the individual data sets are easily fitted directly with scipy's curve_fit routine.

Comment: @Nathan checkout my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The idea:**
create *N* naive, easy to calculate, sufficiently precise(for clustering), approximations. Then "classify" each data-point to the closest such approximation.
This is done like this:

- The approximations are analytical approximations using these two equations I derived:

[image]

[image]

where (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are coordinates of two points on the curve.

- To get these two points **I assumed** that (1) the first points(according to the x-axis) are distributed equally between the different real curves. And (2) the 2 first points of each real curve, are smaller or bigger than the 2 first points of each other real curve. Thus sorting them and dividing into *N* groups will successfully cluster the first *2*N* points.  **If these assumptions are false** you can still manually classify the 2 first points of each real curve and the rest will be classified automatically (this is actually the first approach I implemented).
- Then cluster rest of the points to each point's closest approximation. Closest meaning with the smallest error.

**Edit:** A stronger approach for the initial approximation could be by calculating *A* and *B* for a couple of pairs of points and using their mean *A* and *B* as the approximation. And maybe even possibly doing K-means on these points/approximations.

**The Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# You should probably edit this variable
NUM_OF_CURVES = 4

# <data> should be a 1-D array containing the Y values of the series
# <x_of_data> should be a 1-D array containing the corresponding X values of the series
data, x_of_data = np.loadtxt('...')

# clustering of first 2*num_of_curves points
# I started at NUM_OF_CURVES instead of 0 because my xs started at 0. 
#     The range (0:NUM_OF_CURVES*2) will probably be better for you.
raw_data = data[NUM_OF_CURVES:NUM_OF_CURVES*3]
raw_xs = x_of_data[NUM_OF_CURVES:NUM_OF_CURVES*3]
sort_ind = np.argsort(raw_data)
Y = raw_data[sort_ind].reshape(NUM_OF_CURVES,-1).T
X = raw_xs[sort_ind].reshape(NUM_OF_CURVES,-1).T

# approximation of A and B for each curve
A = ((Y[0]*Y[1])*(X[0]-X[1]))/(Y[1]-Y[0])  
B = (A / Y[0]) - X[0] 

# creating approximating curves
f = []
for i in range(NUM_OF_CURVES):
    f.append(A[i]/(x_of_data+B[i]))
curves = np.vstack(f)

# clustering the points to the approximating curves
raw_clusters = [[] for _ in range(NUM_OF_CURVES)]
for i in range(len(data)):
    raw_clusters[np.abs(curves[:,i]-data[i]).argmin()].append((x_of_data[i],data[i]))

# changing the clusters to np.arrays of the shape (2,-1) 
# where row 0 contains the X coordinates and row 1 the Y coordinates
clusters = []
for i in range(len(raw_clusters)):
    clusters.append(np.array(list(zip(*raw_clusters[i]))))
```

**Example:**

raw series:
[image]

separated series:
[image]

Comment: Where did A() and B() come from at the start? That seems like a random couple of equations. Maybe there is an outside source not mentioned?

Comment: This looks like exactly what I am looking for, but could you elaborate on how you got A and B because I hope to scale this up to some more complex equations with perhaps more unknowns.

Comment: I don't think this will work with the wrong approximations of A and B. How did you determine them?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you sure do have an interesting problem.

I see that there are curves with Y-axis values that are considerably larger than the rest of them. I would simply take the first N-values with the largest Y-axis values and then fit them to an exponential decay curve (or that other curve you mention). You can then simply take the points that most fit that curve and then leave the other points alone.

## Except...

This is a terrible way to extrapolate data. Doing this, you are cherry-picking the data you want. This is falsifying information and is very bad.

Your best bet is to create a single curve that all points fit too if you cannot isolate all of those points into separate curves with external information.

## But...

We do know some information: a valid function must have only 1 output given a single input.

If the X-Axis is discreet, this means you can create a lookup table of Outputs given the input. This allows you to count how many curves there are associated with the specific X-value (which could be a time unit). In other words, you have to have external information to separate points locally. You can then reorder the points in increasing Y-value, and now you have your separate curves defined in discrete points.

Basically, this is an unsolvable problem in the general sense, but in your specific application, there might be extra rules that further define the domain and range such that you can do data filtering.

## One more thing...

I am making these statements with the assumption that the (X,Y) values are floats that cannot maintain accuracy after some mathematical operations.

If you are using things like [unum numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unum_(number_format)), you might be able to keep enough information in the decimal such that your fitting functions can differentiate between points without extra filtering.

This case is more of a hope than anything, as adopting a new number representation to get more accuracy to isolate sampled points is a stretch at best.

Just for completeness, there are some mathematical libraries that might help you.

1. Boost.uBLAS
2. Eigen
3. LAPACK++

Hopefully, I have given you enough information to allow you to solve your problem.

Comment: *This is falsifying information and is very bad.* Kind of depends on how you intend this data be used. Great wealth and power could be yours. Muhuhahahahahahahahahahahahahahaha!

Comment: Please see my answer to this question, which includes a graphical Python fitter.

Answer (score 1):

I extracted data from the plot for analysis. Here is example code that loads, separates, fits and plots the three data sets. It works when the separate data files are appended into a single text file.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


##########################################################
# data load and separation section

datafilename = 'temp.dat'
textdata = open(datafilename, 'rt').read()


xLists = [[], [], []]
yLists = [[], [], []]

previousY = 0.0 # initialize
whichList = -1 # initialize
datalines = textdata.split('\n')
for line in datalines:
    if not line: # allow for blank lines in data file
        continue
    spl = line.split()
    x = float(spl[0])
    y = float(spl[1])

    if y > previousY + 50.0: # this separator must be greater than max noise
        whichList += 1
    previousY = y

    xLists[whichList].append(x)
    yLists[whichList].append(y)



##########################################################
# curve fitting section

def func(x, a, b):
    return a / x + b


parameterLists = []
for curveIndex in range(len(xLists)):
    # these are the same as the scipy defaults
    initialParameters = numpy.array([1.0, 1.0])

    xData = numpy.array(xLists[curveIndex], dtype=float)
    yData = numpy.array(yLists[curveIndex], dtype=float)

    # curve fit the test data
    fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, initialParameters)

    parameterLists.append(fittedParameters)


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    for curveIndex in range(len(xLists)):
        # first the raw data as a scatter plot
        axes.plot(xLists[curveIndex], yLists[curveIndex],  'D')

        # create data for each fitted equation plot
        xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xLists[curveIndex]), max(xLists[curveIndex]))
        yModel = func(xModel, *parameterLists[curveIndex])

        # now the model as a line plot
        axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: OP does not have 3 data sets. OP has 1 data set.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, but the initial data is not separated but one data set, and the problem is with separating them, not curve fitting them.

Comment: If the data is randomly mixed together rather than appended, please state this clearly. As I clearly stated in my answer, this code works when the data is appended into one data set.